# How to `pip install pyside` on virtualenv in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, qt, virtualenv, pyside

I want to install pyside on my virtualenv on OS X  Mavericks so that I can keep my files clean. But I am unable to install it, and I got the errors.

I have installed Xcode 5.1.1 (latest for now) and the Command Line Tools. I have installed homebrew.

I have a homebrew-ed python and qt(4). I know I may `brew install pyside` but I don't want to do that. I just want all the project-level stuffs in virtualenv.

Here are my logs (I am using zsh and oh-my-zsh):

```
➜  ~  brew install python qt
# ...
# everything is ok
➜  ~  pip install virtualenv
# ...
# everything is ok
➜  ~  
➜  ~  brew list
brew-cask   gdbm        isl     libxml2     pcre        readline
cairo       gettext     jpeg        libyaml     pixman      sqlite
cloog       gfortran    libffi      mpfr        pkg-config  swig
cmake       glib        libmpc      node        python      tree
fontconfig  gmp     libpng      openssl     qt      wget
freetype    htop-osx    libtiff     p7zip       r
➜  ~  
➜  ~  virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
➜  ~  
➜  ~  source venv/bin/activate
(venv)➜  ~  pip install pyside
Downloading/unpacking pyside
  Real name of requirement pyside is PySide
  Downloading PySide-1.2.1.tar.gz (9.3MB): 9.3MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/Users/auser/venv/build/pyside/setup.py) egg_info for package pyside
# ...
# wait for it
# ...
1 warning generated.

[ 70%] Building CXX object libshiboken/CMakeFiles/libshiboken.dir/sbkconverter.cpp.o

In file included from /Users/auser/venv/build/pyside/sources/shiboken/libshiboken/sbkconverter.cpp:26:

/Users/auser/venv/build/pyside/sources/shiboken/ext/sparsehash/google/dense_hash_map:97:10: fatal error: 'tr1/functional' file not found

#include HASH_FUN_H                  // defined in config.h

         ^

/Users/auser/venv/build/pyside/sources/shiboken/ext/sparsehash/google/sparsehash/sparseconfig.h:18:24: note: expanded from macro 'HASH_FUN_H'

    #define HASH_FUN_H <tr1/functional>

                       ^

1 error generated.

make[2]: *** [libshiboken/CMakeFiles/libshiboken.dir/sbkconverter.cpp.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [libshiboken/CMakeFiles/libshiboken.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

error: Error compiling shiboken

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/auser/venv/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/auser/venv/build/pyside/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/t4/pqnck28j69z57hbgp74dzwg40000gn/T/pip-Scd8Bi-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/auser/venv/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/auser/venv/build/pyside
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/auser/.pip/pip.log
(venv)➜  ~
```

I have googled it but I cannot find any useful ideas. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you include the results of your `brew doctor`?

Comment: `(venv)➜  ~  brew doctor        
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably \`chown\` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/de
    /usr/local/share/man/de/man1

Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated.
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours, this is a long time in brewland!
To update Homebrew, run \`brew update\`.`

Comment: @JonathanHoward I think nothing is serious with brew doctor. I started to install qt yesterday.